# What happens when $G$ is an infinite group?

Tags: group-theory

I will be honest and say that I am currently doing an assignment question on group theory, but would like some confirmation with something I'm not 100% sure of. I do not want an answer for my question, but a hint would be greatly appreciated. I will also share my thoughts on the problem.

The question is as follows

> Let $G$ be a finite group and let $g$ be an element of odd order $n$. Show that $g=(g^2)^k$ for some integer $k\geq 1$. Does this result still hold when $G$ is an infinite group?

I have shown the first part of the question without too much difficulty.

For the second part, I feel that the result still holds if $G$ is infinite, because my working out for the first part uses only the fact that the order is $n$ (so $g^n=e$) and that $n$ is odd. It didn't use anything to do with the fact that $G$ is finite or infinite$. Is my thinking too simplistic and naive here?

Comment: Your argument works for the second part. If you want to make it more precise, consider the inclusion $\langle{g}\rangle \to G$ with $\langle{g\rangle}$ finite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your thinking is fine. The only part of $G$ that is relevant in the context of a specific $g$ is the cyclic subgroup it generates $\langle g\rangle$ - anything else about the group (like how many elements it has, what kind of orders they have, etc.) is irrelevant. In general, if you have a proof which only used a certain set of hypotheses, then you don't need any more hypotheses to get the conclusion (although sometimes it can be tricky to keep track of what hypotheses one is using).